# Faking HTTPS on mobile

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to force HTTPS on mobile?

I'm working on a site that uses microphone and voice recognition as a main interaction, unfortunately every time I try to use it, it asks me to allow my microphone, which really disrupts the whole thing.

Is there any way I can make the browser think it's using https even when it's not?

Or, alternatively, is there any other solution to get the website to stop asking me for my permission?

Comment: What level of control do you have over how the website is served to your mobile device? Could you *actually* set up HTTPS? If you don't want to pay for a cert, could you use a self-signed one, or will this website be used by the general public?

Comment: I can pay for an HTPPS certificate on my current web hosting, but I'd rather not pay the money if possible. The website is just for testing purposes, not for the public.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing you can do with it. It would be a security hole